# How to check if two [String: Any] are identical?

Tags: swift, swift3

Is there any way to check if two [String: Any] are identical ?

```
let actual: [[String: Any]] = [
    ["id": 12345, "name": "Rahul Katariya"],
    ["id": 12346, "name": "Aar Kay"]
]
var expected: [[String: Any]]!

if actual == expected {
    print("Equal")
}
```

Basically i want Dictionary to conform to Equatable protocol in Swift 3.

Comment: First of all both actual and expected are Arrays not dictionary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For **Xcode 7.3, swift 2.2**
A dictionary is of type : `[String:AnyObject]` or simply put `NSDictionary`

```
let actual: [String: AnyObject] = ["id": 12345, "name": "Rahul Katariya"]


var expected: [String: AnyObject] = ["id": 12346, "name": "Aar Kay"]


print(NSDictionary(dictionary: actual).isEqualToDictionary(expected))//False
```

---

For **Xcode 8.beta 6, Swift 3**

Dictionary is defined as:

```
struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> : Collection, ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral
```

NSDictionary has the following convenience initializer:

```
convenience init(dictionary otherDictionary: [AnyHashable : Any])
```

So you can use AnyHashable type for Key and Any type for Value

```
let actual: [String: Any] = ["id": 12345, "name": "Rahul Katariya"]

var expected: [String: Any] = ["id": 12346, "name": "Aar Kay"]


print(NSDictionary(dictionary: actual).isEqual(to: expected))//False
```

Comment: your code doesn't even compile with Swift 3 • Xcode 8 beta 6

Comment: As of beta 6 your dictionary should be `[AnyHashable: Any]` and `isEqualToDictionary` now is `.isEqual(to:)`

Comment: @LeoDabus any edits regarding updating my answer are welcome , Thank you.. :)

Comment: Dictionary as of beta 6 is defined as `Dictionary<Hashable,Value>` so you can use AnyHashable for Key and Any for Value

Comment: @LeoDabus For some reason the comparison using `NSDictionary`'s `isEqual` (as described above and in your linked answer) always returns `false` for me [when testing in the IBM Swift Playground](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57c17bb2832e21c974ef4736) (Swift 3.0 Aug 25 version). If you have XCode 8 beta 6 (I don't), could you verify that this works as intended for Swift 3 there?

Comment: @dfri yes it does at least for the example above. I will test it again later and let you know.

Comment: @LeoDabus I see, maybe something with the IBM sandbox then, thanks! Have a nice evening :)

Comment: Hello, I'm new to Swift - having 4.2. It seems swift is not completely backward compatible(?).

Answer (score 5):

With Swift 5.5 you can easily cast it to `NSDictionary`, as it always succeeds:

```
XCTAssertEqual(actual as NSDictionary, expected as NSDictionary)
```

Answer (score 4):

Conformance to `Equatable` aside; for the exercise you *could* write your own `isEqual` function to compare two `[T: Any]` dictionaries for a subset of (`Equatable`) types that you know the value wrapped by `Any` is limited to. By attempted conversion to these types (e.g. in a `switch` statement, as below), you could compare the dictionary's values (for each given key) one by one *after* their conversion to these given types. E.g.

```
// Usable if the 'Any' values in your dict only wraps
// a few different types _that are known to you_.
// Return false also in case value cannot be successfully 
// converted to some known type. This might yield a false negative.
extension Dictionary where Value: Any {
    func isEqual(to otherDict: [Key: Any], 
                 allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown: Bool = false) -> Bool {
        guard allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown && 
            self.count == otherDict.count else { return false }
        for (k1,v1) in self {
            guard let v2 = otherDict[k1] else { return false }
            switch (v1, v2) {
                case (let v1 as Double, let v2 as Double) : if !(v1.isEqual(to: v2)) { return false }
                case (let v1 as Int, let v2 as Int) : if !(v1==v2) { return false } 
                case (let v1 as String, let v2 as String): if !(v1==v2) { return false }
                // ... fill in with types that are known to you to be 
                // wrapped by the 'Any' in the dictionaries
                default: return false
            }
        }
    return true
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
/* example setup */
var dict1: [String: Any] = ["id": 12345, "name": "Rahul Katariya", "weight": 70.7]
var dict2: [String: Any] = ["id": 12346, "name": "Aar Kay", "weight": 83.1]

/* example usage */
print(dict1.isEqual(to: dict2, allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown: true))
    // false

dict2["name"] = "Rahul Katariya"
dict2["weight"] = 70.7

print(dict1.isEqual(to: dict2, allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown: true)) 
    // false

dict2["id"] = 12345

print(dict1.isEqual(to: dict2, allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown: true)) 
    // true

class Foo {}
dict1["id"] = Foo()
dict2["id"] = Foo()

print(dict1.isEqual(to: dict2, allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown: true))  
    // false! (we haven't implemented this attempted conversion!)

// incompatable keys cause error as expected an intended    
let dict3: [Int: Any] = [1:2]
dict1.isEqual(to: dict3)
    /* error: cannot convert value of type '[Int : Any]' 
              to expected argument type '[String : Any]' */
```

Just note the danger that the `as` conversion may yield a false positive (`true`) as it can allow mapping from two different types to a common other type, e.g. slicing away derived class differences when casting two derived class instances to their common parent type:

```
class Base: Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool { return true }

class DerivedA : Base {
    let foo = "foo"
}

class DerivedB : Base {
    let bar = 4.2
}

let a = DerivedA()
let b = DerivedB()

switch (a, b) {
    case (let a as Base, let b as Base): print(a == b) 
    default: ()
} // sliced by conversion! prints "true"
```

---

If you'd rather like a failed "known types conversion" to return `nil` (whereas successful conversions will always yield `true`/`false`, based on subsequent equality testing), you could extend the above to (the even messier)

```
// a 'nil' return here would correspond to an invalid call
extension Dictionary where Value: Any {
    func isEqual(to otherDict: [Key: Any], 
                 allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown: Bool = false) -> Bool? {
        guard allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown else { return nil } 
        guard self.count == otherDict.count else { return false }
        for (k1,v1) in self {
            guard let v2 = otherDict[k1] else { return false }
            switch (v1, v2) {
                case (let v1 as Double, let v2 as Double) : if !(v1.isEqual(to: v2)) { return false }
                case (let v1 as Int, let v2 as Int) : if !(v1==v2) { return false } 
                case (let v1 as String, let v2 as String): if !(v1==v2) { return false }
                // ... 
                case (_ as Double, let v2): if !(v2 is Double) { return false }
                case (_, _ as Double): return false
                case (_ as Int, let v2): if !(v2 is Int) { return false }
                case (_, _ as Int): return false
                case (_ as String, let v2): if !(v2 is String) { return false }
                case (_, _ as String): return false 
                default: return nil
            }
        }
    return true
    } 
}

/* Example as per above will yield (printout):

       Optional(false)
       Optional(false)
       Optional(true)
       nil                           */
```

Note however that the value by value equality testing above is short-circuited in case of a `false` hit, which mean that depending on the random order of the non-ordered dictionaries (non-ordered collection), a special case may return `nil` as well as `false`, given two non-equal dictionaries. This special case occurs for two dictionary of non-equal values (non-equality for a known type value-value pair) which also hold an value type not included in the attempted casting: if the non-equality of known types is hit first, `false` will be returned, whereas if a failed conversion is hit first, `nil` will be returned. Either way, a `nil` return means the call should be considered invalid, as caller stated that `allPossibleValueTypesAreKnown` was `true` (which a failed conversion implies is `false`).

Answer (score 3):

The type `Any` is not `Equatable` in Swift, so any collection types including `Any` cannot be `Equatable`.

You can write something like this in Swift 3/Xcode 8 beta 6:

```
if actual as NSArray == expected as NSArray {
    print("Equal")
}
```

But, as *importing `id` as `Any`* is just introduced in beta 6, so this behaviour may change in the near future.